# problemas de Segment Tree Java

Tags: java, array, netbeans, matrices, herencia

intento resolver este ejercicio del libro competitive programming ejercicio **
Ejercicio 2.4.3.2 *: en esta sección, hemos visto cómo se pueden usar los árboles de segmentos para responder
Consultas mínimas de rango (RMQ). Los árboles de segmentos también se pueden usar para responder dinámicas
Consultas de suma de rango (RSQ (i, j)), es decir, una suma de A [i] + A [i + 1] + ... + A [j]. Modificar
el código del árbol de segmentos dado arriba para tratar con RSQ.**
este es el codigo

````
    private int rmq(int nodo, int izq, int der, int i, int j) { // O(log n)     
        if (j < izq || der < i)     // si (i..j) est� fuera del rango [izq..der] retorna -1
            return -1;              
        if (i <= izq && der <= j)   // si (i..j) est� dentro del rango [izq..der] retorna ads[p]
            return segmento[nodo];
        int nodoIzq = nodo << 1; // nodo * 2;
        int nodoDer = (nodo << 1) + 1; // nodo * 2 + 1
        int mitad = (izq + der) / 2;

        // calcula la posici�n del elemento m�nimo del segmento izquierdo y derecho
        int p1 = rmq(nodoIzq, izq,     mitad, i, j);
        int p2 = rmq(nodoDer, mitad + 1, der, i, j);

        if (p1 == -1)
            return p2;
        if (p2 == -1)
            return p1;
        return (vector[p1] <= vector[p2]) ? p1 : p2;
    }

    public int rmq(int i, int j) {
        return rmq(1, 0, n - 1, i, j);
    }```
y este es mi codigo RMQ

    private int rmq(int nodo, int izq, int der, int i, int j) { // O(log n)
        if (j < izq || der < i)     // si (i..j) est� fuera del rango [izq..der] retorna -1
            return -1;              
        if (i <= izq && der <= j)   // si (i..j) est� dentro del rango [izq..der] retorna ads[p]
            return segmento[nodo];

        int nodoIzq = nodo << 1; // nodo * 2;
        int nodoDer = (nodo << 1) + 1; // nodo * 2 + 1
        int mitad = (izq + der) / 2;


        int p1 = rmq(nodoIzq, izq,     mitad, i, j);
        int p2 = rmq(nodoDer, mitad + 1, der, i, j);

        if (p1 == -1)
            return p2;

        if (p2 == -1)
            return p1;

        return vector[p1]+vector[p2];

        }

    public int rmq(int i, int j) {
        return rmq(1, 0, n - 1, i, j);
    }


pero la respuesta me sale convarios errores al llamar la funcion

    System.out.printf("RMQ(1, 7) = %d\n", ads.rmq(1, 7));

Output codigo: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 49
    at arbol_de_segmentos.ArbolDeSegmentos.rmq(ArbolDeSegmentos.java:66)
    at arbol_de_segmentos.ArbolDeSegmentos.rmq(ArbolDeSegmentos.java:56)
    at arbol_de_segmentos.ArbolDeSegmentos.rmq(ArbolDeSegmentos.java:71)
    at arbol_de_segmentos.EjemploArbolDeSegmentosMinimo.main(EjemploArbolDeSegmentosMinimo.java:20)
C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
`
````

Comment: Uno de tus puntos se esta saliendo del tamaño del vector, pero aun no descubro cual ni tampoco he descubierto donde declaras la variable n... creo que la clave se encuentra en mirar los contenidos de p1 y p2.

Comment: Podrias decirnos porfavor cual es el tamaño del vector inicialmente?? o editar la pregunta y colocar donde declaras tu vector?, si sabemos el tamaño de tu vector podremos ayudarte de manera mas facil. pero sin saberlo estamos un poco a ciegas...